# Overriding Rails to_param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I get the to_param method to deliver keyword slugs all the time?  I have trouble getting it to work with this route:

map.pike '/auction/:auction_id/item/:id', :controller => 'items', :action => 'show'

Earlier the overridden to_param was working for

'items/1-cashmere-scarf'

but fails with `'auction/123/item/1'`

Update:

I'm not sure if the syntax is correct[(edit: it's correct: it works :-)], or even efficient.... but using haml, I found that the following code works to generate the desired link ('auction/:auction_id/item/:id')

```
- for auction in @auctions.sort{|a, b| a.scheduled_start <=> b.scheduled_start}
  -for item in @items
    - unless auction.current_auction
      ... pike_path(auction.auction_id, item)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question. (it's 3:41 AM here)

From what I see, you directly access `auction_id` method, instead of using `pike_path(auction, item)` that'd use `#to_param`.

Also, it might fail for `auction/123/item/1` because you haven't changed your controller.

I think it'd be helpful to describe how to get working slugs.

Broadly speaking, if you override `#to_param`, IDs no longer works. It means, that if you go with slugs, every time polymorpic URL is generated (eg, `link_to object, object`), it passes to_param's value. It is worth noting that you must change your controller as well.

Personally I think that the best way to generate slugs easily is to use techno-weenie's [permalink_fu](http://github.com/technoweenie/permalink_fu/tree/master), adding `has_permalink` to your model, and then, override `to_param`. For example

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_permalink :title, :slug
end
```

assuming that you have slug, a string field, and want to slugize your title.

You also need to adjust your controller:

```
class AuctionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @auction = Auction.find_by_slug(params[:id]) || raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
    end
end
```

Then, you can generate routes, in the views, this way:

```
link_to @action, @action
```

By the way, you should NOT sort your actions in the view. The best way is to use `named_scope`.

Comment: you can use `find_by_slug!` which raises exception unless found